# sqlalchemy event on column update

Tags: python, session, events, orm, sqlalchemy

I registered an event at updating `User.name` for apply some rules after or just before update.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import event
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)   # engine part

Base = declarative_base()


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    fullname = Column(String)
    password = Column(String)
    rule = Column(String)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)


session = Session()
u1 = User(id=1, name="hello world", fullname="hello kitty")
u2 = User(id=2, name="hello world2", fullname="hello kitty2")
session.add(u1)
session.add(u2)


@event.listens_for(User, 'before_update')
def User_before_update(target, value, initiator):
    print ":::::received before insert event for target"


@event.listens_for(User.name, 'set')
def name_set(target, value, old_value, initiator):
    print ":::::set before insert event for target"


### option A
user = session.query(User).get(2)
user.name = u"wawamsma"
session.merge(user)

### option B
session.query(User).filter(User.id == 2).update({User.name: u"eenimenee"})
```

#### option A

Every things works fine, but I have some update method using many fields to sqlalchemy.

#### option B

Updated, but do not trigger both print func.

So I wonder, is this the Wrong way to register event or wrong way to do the update?

Answer (score 8):

To receive events when using the query.update() method, you need to use the [after_bulk_update](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html?highlight=bulk_update#sqlalchemy.orm.events.SessionEvents.after_bulk_update) event.   As this operation does not deal with individual objects and instead emits an UPDATE statement directly, the actual objects in memory which may have been affected here are not locally available; you may need to query for them.  The context will have a `matched_objects` attribute if "synchronize_session" is set to "evaluate".